# using shared_from_this goes to bad_weak_ptr(ros2)

Tags: smart-pointers, ros2

my code is like this

in A.cpp

```
#include "rclcpp_lifecycle/rclcpp_lifecycle.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"
#include "D.hpp"

class A : public B, public rclcpp_lifecycle::LifecycleNode
{
    A();
    virtual ~A();

    on_configure(...)
    {
        func_A()
    }

    func_A()
    {
        D::func_D(B::shared_from_this());
    }
};
```

in D.cpp

```
class D
{
    D();
    ~D();

    static func_D(shared_ptr<B>){}
};
```

in main.cpp

```
#include "A.hpp"

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> node = make_shared<A>("a");
    rclcpp::spin(node);
}
```

then, in func_A, throw bad_weak_ptr
I think that rclcpp::spin keeps the shared_ptr of A, but it doesn't

what am i missing?

Comment: My psychic powers tell me that `B` derives from `enable_shared_from_this<B>`. This means that `A` derives multiply from `enable_shared_from_this` (because [LifecycleNode also derives from `enable_shared_from_this`](https://docs.ros2.org/latest/api/rclcpp_lifecycle/classrclcpp__lifecycle_1_1LifecycleNode.html)), which prevents `shared_from_this` from working.

Comment: B derives from enable_shared_from_this<B> already. As you say, A derives multiply from B, LifecycleNode. So, I used shared_from_this - B::shared_from_this()

Comment: I don't think you read my answer. Deriving multiple times from `enable_shared_from_this` **prevents `shared_from_this` from working.** You are allowed only a single inheritance from `enable_shared_from_this`.

Comment: you mean multiple `enable_shared_from_this` doesn't work, so it returns `bad_weak_ptr`, right?
then in my case, how can i implement?

Comment: Use `LifetimeNode`'s `shared_from_this` and then convert the `shared_ptr<LifetimeNode>` to `shared_ptr<B>`.

Comment: holy.. really thanks Raymond!!

Comment: i solved with your idea
`func_A()
{
    D::func_D(std::static_pointer_cast<A>(shared_from_this());
}`

Comment: Go ahead and post this as an answer